# How to create CSS for giving proportional margin

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to create 3 buttons inside the div container. The space below the buttons must always be double the space above the buttons. How can we write CSS to achieve this? I have attached to image for a clear understanding.

(Here 1H signifies ratio meaning if the space above is 1H then the space below will be 2H)

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="upper-div></div>
  <div class="lower-div">
    <button class="btn-1">1</button>
    <button class="btn-2">1</button>
    <button class="btn-3">1</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I want to know the CSS to create such design using HTML and CSS only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could probably achieve this with CSS grid:

```css
.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 4fr 6fr;
  height: 100vh;
  background: skyblue;
}

.upper-div {
  background: yellow;
}

.lower-div {
  background: bisque;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 36px 2fr;
}

.lower-div > button {
  grid-row: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="upper-div"></div>
  <div class="lower-div">
    <button class="btn-1">1</button>
    <button class="btn-2">1</button>
    <button class="btn-3">1</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hello, I had the same thinking as you, but what does the .lower-div > button line mean? It seems like a clever way to avoid adding an extra div for the buttons and it also styles the buttons to stretch across the entire width

Comment: In CSS the `>` is a [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator), aka "direct child" selector. It matches only buttons that are direct children of `.lower-div`. The stretching is the result of the default justify/stretch rules on the `.lower-div` grid.

Comment: I see, thanks! It seems like by assigning all 3 buttons to grid-row 2 implicitly creates 3 grid-columns with equal width, stretching the buttons to fit

Comment: Right. I guess I could've been explicit about it, but I was in a hurry and trying to keep it as minimal as possible.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about Grid. It solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.main {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: beige;
}

.upper-div {
    height: 40%;
    width: auto;
    background-color: tan;
}

.lower-div{
    height: 60%;
    width: auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 36px 2fr;
}

.buttons {
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
    display: flex;
}

.btn {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
      <div class="main">
        <div class="upper-div"></div>
        <div class="lower-div">
          <div class="buttons">
            <button class="btn">Button 1</button>
            <button class="btn">Button 2</button>
            <button class="btn">Button 3</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

One way is to use a grid system. In this example, I made a grid with 3 rows, with the size of [1 fr](https://medium.com/@r_tripti/css-grids-all-about-fr-units-36b7b5fea661) (1H in your diagram), 36px and 2 fr (2H in your diagram). After that, I created a div to house the buttons, and inserted this div into the second row of the grid.